# validating / sanitizing google results for posting online

Tags: privacy, url, google-search

i sometimes want to link to a search result page of Google services.
but the address bar URL is "dirty"

```
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&lr=&cites=415785132359889643&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ei=7c7VUOLpJ4zdsgaA94HYBg&ved=0CEIQzgIwAA
```

Sometimes i clean it by hand but would love to hear of a smarter method.
there are [urlValidators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194284/how-can-i-clean-and-sanitize-a-url-submitted-by-a-user-for-redisplay-in-java)  that i understand do just that, if i need a small php script thats ok.